# How to display html page (html code stored in variable)

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

```
<Template>
   {{variable}}
</template>

<script>
 export default {
  data(){
   return {
    variable: "<ul><li>Sample</li><li>text></li></ul>"
   }
  }
 }
</script>
```

Expected result:

- Sample
- text

Actual Result:
`<ul><li>Sample</li><li>text</li></ul>`

I need to display the html page. Where html codes are stored in the variable. for example, I have given the simple code above. Now the problem is the page takes the variable as string while displaying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use v-html.

```
<Template>
  <div
     v-html="variable"
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way, it will help:

--JS code --

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
  data: {
    variable: null,
  },
  created() {
    this.variable=`<ul><li>Sample</li><li>text</li></ul>`;
  },
});
```

-- HTML code --

```
<body>
   <Template>
   <div id="app">
   <div v-html="variable"></div>
   </div>
   </Template>
</body>
```